# MySQL UPDATE with subqueries and join

Tags: mysql, database

Hi i am new to subqueries and so not sure if i am doing right

I am happy with this

```
SELECT t2.cons, t1.date, t1.account_no  FROM
(
SELECT date, account_no FROM  tbl_consignment_x3
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT cons, date, account_no FROM
tbl_volume_analysis 
) t2
ON t2.account_no=t1.account_no AND t2.date=t1.date
```

It gives me the results i want to use

So i was hoping something like this below would do what i want but i can't get the syntax right plus i'm not sure if my technique is completely wrong

```
UPDATE tbl_margin_all t3 
(
SELECT t2.cons, t1.date, t1.account_no  FROM
(
SELECT date, account_no FROM  tbl_consignment_x3
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT cons, date, account_no FROM
tbl_volume_analysis 
) t2
ON t2.account_no=t1.account_no AND t2.date=t1.date 
)
SET t3.cons=t2.cons 
WHERE t1.date=t3.date AND t1.account_no=t3.account_no
```

thanks

ADDITION:
First i do a total count of consignments for a particular date taken from consignment table that is then written in volume table with the date and account.. then from consignments table i want to write to each consignment that count that i did.

Comment: You need to tell us what do you want and what error you are getting. Did you try reading mysql documentation around update queries and syntax?

Comment: Hi yes i spent 3 hours trying to solve so i've looked around alot! First i do a total count of consignments for a particular date. that is written in volume table.. then from consignments table i want to write to each consignment that count that i did. I'll put this in my question as an addition. thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the comma after t3 for syntax

```
UPDATE tbl_margin_all_4000 t3,
(
    SELECT cons, t1.date, t1.account_no FROM
    (
        SELECT date, account_no, consignment_no FROM tbl_consignment_x3_4000
    ) t1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT cons, date, account_no FROM
        tbl_volume_analysis_4000 
    ) t2
    ON t2.account_no=t1.account_no AND t2.date=t1.date 
) as src
SET t3.cons=src.cons
WHERE t3.date=src.date AND t3.account_no=src.account_no
```

this query took 4 mins. i had tried the double joins as suggested kindly but that took 45 mins.

Comment: This is essentially the same as my query, it's just using archaic cross-product syntax instead of ANSI JOIN. But the SQL engine treats them identically.

Comment: I can see they get the same result but my way gets it in 4 mins as opposed to 45 mins. from what i can see from other posts on stack overflow sub query in this instance is the faster option. Could you let me and others know why you think my way would be wrong as 'archaic' implies. again i thank you for your time and i am here to learn. I'm a week into my first subquery so i know nothing. thanks again Barma

Comment: I didn't notice yesterday that yours has nested subqueries, that could make a difference. It would help if you indented your code to show the structure.

Comment: i can see below you have colour coded your query commands .. is that a function in stackoverflow? thx

Comment: Dude . you haven't indented your code ha ha. Again i do appreciate you helping me but ...... come on man! where's the love!

Comment: Syntax highlighting is done by SO. Use a code block instead of `<pre>` and it will be highlighted.

Comment: I have nothing nested in my answer, so there's nothing to indented.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join with the first subquery -- put `JOIN` after `t3`.

Actually, you don't need any of the subqueries at all, you can just join directly with the tables.

```
UPDATE tbl_margin_all AS t3
JOIN tbl_consignment_x3 AS t1 ON t1.date = t3.date AND t1.account_no=t3.account_no
JOIN tbl_volume_analysis AS t2 ON t2.account_no=t1.account_no AND t2.date=t1.date 
SET t3.cons = t2.cons
```

It's the same in the `SELECT` query, it should be:

```
SELECT t2.cons, t1.date, t1.account_no  
FROM tbl_consignment_x3 AS t1
JOIN tbl_volume_analysis AS t2
ON t2.account_no=t1.account_no AND t2.date=t1.date
```

Comment: This works perfectly. thanks very much indeed Barmar!

Comment: although your version works the query is so slow it's unusable for me and i have now been trying again to have a go the way i was trying to do it before .. still struggling with the syntax! like a dog with a bone i'll keep gnawing at it

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on the columns being used in the joins.

Comment: yes thanks. i have account no and date indexed . let me know if i need to index anything else .. thanks for your comment

Comment: indexed in all 3 tables. is that ok? thankyou .. just checked and i hadn't indexed in my margin_all table .. have indexed cons in both tables .. getting excited now. thanks!